# Dynamic text display on mouseover of images and SEO

Tags: javascript, seo, onmouseover

With HTML page content that contains images but no text what would be the implications to SEO if there were dynamic text rendered over text showing in the images. Not title text but actual div elements containing text positioned exactly over text in the image. I am not sure but seems to me Google is using this tactic in the Preview of PDF documents from Google Drive.

The pages appear to be images and text but text seems to be dynamically displayed over the (text in) the image on demand - by cursor selecting of text inside a "highlight" element on the page...

I am wondering if we implement this dynamic solution will it help or hurt SEO ? Will dynamic Text be considered content and thereby indexed ?

Comment: What is the question? I don't seem to get what you are asking here.

Comment: Ask this question here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com Also, you have 4 more questions that have not been accepted.